# Assembly.GetType("[...]", true); throws TypeLoadException

Tags: c#

My code:

```
//App, Core.cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Game
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "mods\\ExampleMod.dll"));
        var x1 = a.GetType("PTF_Mod.Mod_Main");
        var x2 = x1.GetMethod("OnStart");
        var x3 = x2.Invoke(null, new object[] { });

        while(true);
    }
}


//App, ModCrew.cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Engine
{
    public static class ModCrew
    {
        public class Mod
        {
            public void ItWorks()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It works!");
            }
        }
    }
}

//DLL, Mod_Main.cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PTF_Mod
{
    public static class Mod_Main
    {
        public static void OnStart()
        {
            var exe = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
            Console.WriteLine(exe.Location); //Location is valid
            var x = exe.GetType("Engine.ModCrew.Mod", true); //But here I get exception
            var y = Activator.CreateInstance(x);

            x.GetMethod("ItWorks", BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(null, object[] { });
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:
An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Nie można załadować typu 'Engine.ModCrew.Mod' z zestawu 'Game, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: `"Engine.ModCrew+Mod"`

Comment: Then TypeLoadException on "var x3 = x2.Invoke(null, new object[] { });" in Core.cs

Comment: "An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: Oh, wait, after testing your answer, I forget to build dll

Comment: @TheChilliPL `OnStart` doesn't take any arguments, do `x2.Invoke(null, null);` instead

Comment: var x3 = x2.Invoke(null, new object[] { });

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ExampleMod.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Odwołanie do obiektu nie zostało ustawione na wystąpienie obiektu.

Comment: The same as above comment - NullReferenceException

Comment: `GetMethod("ItWorks", BindingFlags.Instance)` -> `GetMethod("ItWorks")`

Comment: The same.
And error isn't on that line...

Comment: Try using `BindingFlags`. `var x2 = x1.GetMethod("OnStart", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)`

Comment: Not working, the same error

Comment: Also use your instance variable here: `x.GetMethod("ItWorks", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Invoke(y, object[] { });`

Comment: x.GetMethod("ItWorks", BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(null, null);

NullReferenceException

Comment: Oh, null...

But on `var x3` line there is

Comment: Your `BindingFlags` is wrong (see previous comment) and that method requires an instance, that's the first parameter on `Invoke`. use your `y` variable there...

Comment: Yeah, I changed it, but in `var x3 = ...` line is NullReferenceException

Comment: is `x2` null? If not the part that's failing is inside the `OnStart` method.

Comment: I didn't change anything and now
`x.GetMethod("ItWorks", BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(y, null);`
is line with NullReferenceException...

Comment: Change that to `x.GetMethod("ItWorks", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Invoke(y, null);`

Comment: @dukedukes Wow, now It works. thanks :)

Comment: And If I'll make property in Mod, how do I change it? (in dll)

Comment: Look into `PropertyInfo`. `Type.GetProperty` and `PropertyInfo.GetValue` would be the methods you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use `BindingFlags` when getting methods via reflection.

Invoking an instance with `MethodInfo.Invoke` requires the instance as the first parameter `MethodInfo.Invoke(MyInstance,...)`

Changes based on comments:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "mods\\ExampleMod.dll"));
    var x1 = a.GetType("PTF_Mod.Mod_Main");
    var x2 = x1.GetMethod("OnStart", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    var x3 = x2.Invoke(null, null);

    while(true);
}
```

Mod_Main:

```
public static void OnStart()
{
    var exe = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    Console.WriteLine(exe.Location); //Location is valid
    var x = exe.GetType("Engine.ModCrew+Mod", true); //But here I get exception
    var y = Activator.CreateInstance(x);

    x.GetMethod("ItWorks", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Invoke(y, null);
}
```

Also, consider if reflection is even necessary, it can make programs overly complicated. If it's necessary you should look into `Dynamic` to avoid a lot of the troubles of invoking methods with reflection